# Stackexchange.Redis configuration for .NET Core in ha mode

Tags: c#, redis

I have a redis 3 servers + 3 sentinels running locally in docker. Testing the setup I'm seeing that the sentinels are doing their job, if I crush the master a new one is elected.

What my test is

1. check docker-compose up logs
2. ssh into my master node and check the Info
3. write something on master
4. check the value on the slaves
5. crush the master
6. trail sentinels logs
7. check the new elected master
8. bring back the ex-master node

So this works all good

Now I'm confused in regarding with something. I want to build a dotnet core 6 app on top of this.

I'm using stackexchange redis, which I can see that on the multiplexer has ConnectSentinel method.

I'm confused, do I need to setup in .net something related to sentinel ? I am living under the impression that this is an infrastructure concern which my app should not be aware. My impression is that I have to only provide a connection to the master and slaves

```
  "172.10.10.10:5660,172.10.10.10:5660,172.10.10.10:5660,password=pass"
```

, am I wrong and I have to set something for sentinel nodes ?
I can see that there is an option in ConfigurationOptions called ServiceName which states

```
        /// <summary>
        /// The service name used to resolve a service via sentinel.
        /// </summary>
        public string? ServiceName { get; set; }
```

Also checking this

https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html

> serviceName={string}  ServiceName null    Used for connecting to a sentinel primary service

I'm not sure what this means.

```
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis" Version="6.0.10" />
     <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.6.70" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this code:

```
 var sentialConfig = new ConfigurationOptions()
            {
                EndPoints = { "172.10.10.10:5660", "172.10.10.10:5660","172.10.10.10:5660" },
                AbortOnConnectFail = false,
                Password = redisConnectionConfig.Password
            };
            foreach (var endPoint in redisConnectionConfig.EndPoints)
            {
                sentialConfig.EndPoints.Add(endPoint);
            }
            var sentinelConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.SentinelConnect(sentialConfig);
            var masterConfig = new ConfigurationOptions()
            {
                ServiceName = "mymaster",
                Password = redisConnectionConfig.Password,
                AllowAdmin = true
            };
            var masterConnection = sentinelConnection.GetSentinelMasterConnection(masterConfig);
```

Don't forget to use `AllowAdmin`.